# Mac Terminal: Could not find or load main class CLASSNAME

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to run a java program through the Terminal on Mac, yet getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class (MY CLASSNAME)
```

I compiled this application with Eclipse, and when I run this with Eclipse, it works fine.
Furthermore, I am in the right directory, as when I type "ls" in the Terminal, it lists all the files, includes the class file I am trying to run.

This is what I type:

```
java mainClass
```

I would very much appreciate help to solve this!

Thank you,

Dean

EDIT: Solution - instead of java mainClass, it must have package too: java startPackage.mainClass

Comment: Does `mainClass` live in a `package`?

Comment: Yes, its in startPackage

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!

Comment: my main class is caesar, java com.company.caesar doesn't work. I can't figure out what is going on.......

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start by making sure you are at the directory above the top level `package`

If the class belongs to the `package` `com.foo.bar`, you want to be in the directory above `com`.

In your case, you want to be in the directory above `startPack`.

Then you need to use the fully qualified name to run the class...

```
java statPack.mainClass
```

For example...

Comment: Ok, that works now. The only problem is that it freezes when it gets to running classes from my imported external jars. Do I have to somehow tell the Terminal I am importing an external Jar?

Comment: Yes, you'll need use the `-cp` parameter to tell Java where it should search for additional resources, for example `java -cp /path/to/Library.jar:/path/to/directory/full/of/classes stackPack.mainClass`  You may need to quote or escape any path elements with spaces ;)

Comment: Thanks! What is the ":" after you wrote jar?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu It's the unix path separator, it's `;` on windows

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the current directory inside your CLASSPATH.

```
java -cp . mainClass
```

To set this globally, you can use `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.` inside `.bash_profile`.

Separately, if your class lives inside a package such as `com.foo.bar`, then you will need to go to the parent directory of `com` and run your application with the full path.

```
java com.foo.bar.mainClass
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the package thing.

Comment: However, now I have another problem: The program freezes once I try to do stuff from my imports. In Eclipse it works fine. Does this mean I have to somehow tell the Terminal that I have additional Build Paths? (I am using classes from other Jars) - is this what you mean by CLASSPATH?

Comment: It's a path separator character, like `;` on Windows, tells the OS how to to "split" the path elements, so you can specify multiple different paths in a single string

Comment: @user3243080, Use `java -cp .:PathToLib1.jar:PathToLib2.jar com.foo.bar.mainClass`.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this on Mac machine and then what I had to do to make it work was:

### Problem Statement:

I had one package xyz under the root of project i.e src/main/java and then inside xyz package I had one class Student.java

my current directory is /Users/username/projectname/src/main/java/xyz:
I can see Student.java exists here 
and I compiled it using javac Student.java

Now I see class file has been created at this location. But when I try to run the class file using java Student
I get the error: Error: Could not find or load main class Student

### Solution:

Now the solution is to go one step back in the directory and go to root path:/Users/username/projectname/src/main/java and run the command

### java xyz.Student

and it will work.

Link to follow: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html

Answer (score 1):

For people dumb like me, make sure you are typing `java HelloWorld` - and **NOT** `java HelloWorld.class` - to run the compiled file with the name `HelloWorld.class`. This is especially so if you are used to hitting the tab key to complete the file name, as the terminal will give you `java HelloWorld.class` if you hit the tab key for autocomplete after typing something like `java He`...

This answer is here because it took 3 sites, including this answer, and 25 mintues before I figured out what I was doing wrong.

**Logic is easy, typing is hard**.

Answer (score 0):

Using the absolute path can also resolve this problem:

```
java -classpath /Users/xingliu/IdeaProjects/springproject/src/main/java/ startPackage.mainClass
```