# "Could not find or load main class" when trying to run Java program from Mac Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I was trying to run a basic Hello World program written in Java using my the Mac Terminal. It gave me an error that said:

```
"Could not find or load main class".
```

The commands that I used to try and run the program were as followed (after I used cd to go to the directory where HelloWorld.java was located):

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

I did some searching and tried using "java -cp . HelloWorld" but no matter what I try, I always get the "Could not find or load main class" error. The code compiles and runs just fine in Eclipse, but I'm wondering what could be the cause of it not working in the Terminal?

My Java version is 1.8.0_20 running on OS X 10.9.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you have a package?

Comment: Yes I do, it's called  "test".

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174947/mac-terminal-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-classname) do anything?

Comment: Thanks Travis, that seems to have done the trick. My mistake was using cd to go inside the package directory rather than the directory right above it. Just to make sure, to compile it when it's in a package I should use    javac test/HelloWorld.java right? Or is there a better way to compile.?

Comment: No trouble, @user3385368. And yes, that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is in a package, Java looks for the `.class` file in that folder.

You need to put the file in a matching folder, then run `java test.HelloWorld`.

Comment: Still giving me the error unfortunately. I navigated to workspace/Project/src/test and tried your command, but to no avail.