# Executing two-class java project in terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I've created java projected consisting of two classes:

HangmanController - where I keep methods
Hangman - where I have my "main" where I run my program

I want to run my program in terminal (OS X), so I go to my .java files folder and then do
    javac *.java
    java Hangman.java
but terminal says "Error: Could not find or load main class main.java"

Can anybody help with that?

Comment: `java -cp . Hangman` = class path for all classes is current directory, and Hangman.class is the main class with `main` method.

Comment: There are *several* answers on this site with that *exact* error. Did you look at any of them?

Answer (score -1):

It is well discussed here .. please refer this link 
[Mac Terminal: Could not find or load main class CLASSNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174947/mac-terminal-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-classname)

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate rather than use the duplicate link within a low quality, essentially link-only answer.